# magento 2: How to wish list on this type design and code?

Tags: magento2

I have no idea how to wish list page design and code so please help this my is work .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override default layout and behavior then first you should add this line in your module.xml file.

```
     <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Wishlist"/>
    </sequence>
```

Override wishlist_index_index.xml and customize whatever you want.

Comment: Which file code add